# Do design patterns increase or decrease the complexity of an Application?

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns

I was just looking at this question about SQL, and followed a [link about DAO to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object). And it mentions as a disadvantage:

> "As with many design patterns, a design pattern increases the complexity of the application." -[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object)

Which suddenly made me wonder where this idea came from (because it lacks a citation). Personally I always considered patterns reduce to complexity of an application, but I might be delusional, so I'm wondering if this complexity is based on something or not.

Thanks.

Comment: link about DOA.. typo :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the person reading the code is aware of design patterns and their concept and is able to identify design patterns in practical use (not just the book examples) then they really do reduce the complexity.

However I've found with a lot of junior developers, which haven't heard much about design patterns or weren't aware of them at all, that they believe their use increases the complexity of the code.

I can understand it: You suddenly have more classes or code to go through to solve what seems to be a simple problem at first. If you're not aware of the benefits of design patterns, hacked solutions always look better.

Comment: I think your answer would be more convincing if you gave a concrete example of a pattern that when applied reduces complexity.

Answer (score 10):

I love design patterns, but they (apart from simple ones like Singleton) **definitely add complexity** to an application. They add some dimension to a design that is not intuitively obvious to a novice designer (and not part of the features of the programming language).

Some people might feel patterns reduce complexity because of the benefits they bring in terms of the software's non-functional requirements such as maintainability, extendability, reusability, etc. However, I disagree and see the benefits as a *return on complexity investment*. Perhaps in some cases patterns reduce complexity, but a theoretical discussion like that sheds more heat than light. Almost none of the answers so far used concrete examples, save https://stackoverflow.com/a/760968/1168342.

To be specific, many patterns increase **[accidental complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_complexity)** of a design by introducing new structures (interfaces, methods, etc.) that weren't present in the design before the pattern was applied.

Let's use [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) as an example.

> Visitor is a way of separating operations from an object structure on which they operate.
> Before the solution with Visitor, the operations are hard-coded into each Element of the object structure. The challenge for the developer is that adding new operations involves modifying the code in the various elements.
>
> After the application of the Visitor pattern, there is an additional class hierarchy of visitors, which encapsulate the operations.
> The flow of
> control in the solution is definitely more complex, and will be harder
> to debug (anyone who has implemented Visitor and tried to follow the
> program flow of [double-dispatched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) calls with [accept/visit](http://www.plantuml.com:80/plantuml/img/ZSj12W8n30NGVKzHPZKkfWVeObo8Lt0VOi1Wsobj37XxEuBIBWGtWP__Vhrpob0WsYhFGEqMHdd4ODfN63b34ZkXFmMc99E5Qd7ioEEMi93GEL3y81gHVj65AyjMtaWDBYjvGAGiinuCeB22K9lJighN7SzouzfrQdHV7NjzfIxyKpldVe8kwD2y0000) will know this).
>
> Understanding and maintaining Visitor functions in terms of
> cohesive units is less complicated than the alternative of coding
> functions into each of the Elements in the fixed structure that is
> visited. This is the benefit of the pattern.

It's difficult to say quantitatively how much increase there is in accidental complexity or how much easier it is to add new operations. I certainly don't agree with answers that make a blanket statement saying in the long-term, complexity is reduced with applying a pattern. It's not like your design "forgets" the double-dispatch added by Visitor's approach, just because you have code which more easily allows operations to be added. The complexity is a price (or tax) you pay to get the benefit in maintainability.

### Patterns still have to be applied

Regardless of one's supposed familiarity with patterns, any given pattern must be *applied* to a solution. That application is going to be different every time (Martin Fowler said [patterns are only half-baked solutions](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/patterns.pdf)). Developers will always have to understand what classes are playing what roles in the existing design, which is subject to the [essential complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_complexity) (the application problem's complexity) that is often non-trivial.

In the best case, understanding a design pattern applied in an application that's already complex may be trivial, but it's not 0 effort:

- Patterns aren't always applied the same way. There are many variants of patterns -- Proxy comes to mind. I'm not sure that everyone *agrees* about how any given pattern should be applied.
- Introducing one pattern (e.g., Strategy to encapsulate algorithms) often leads to other patterns to manage things properly (e.g., Factory to instantiate the concrete Strategies).
- Introducing a pattern often leads to more responsibilities. Object cleanup when a Factory is used is not trivial (and also not documented in GoF). How many know about the so-called [Lapsed-listener problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapsed_listener_problem)?
- What happens if there is a change in the assumptions made about the need for the pattern (e.g., there is no longer a need to have multiple encapsulated algorithms provided by the Strategy pattern)? It's going to be extra work to remove the pattern later. If you don't remove it, new developers could be duped by its presence when they come on board. Patterns are intertwined between the classes playing the roles in the pattern. Removal is not trivial.

[Erich Gamma gave an anecdote at ECOOP 2006](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11785477_1) that designers in one case decided to *remove* the [Abstract Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) from a commercial multi-platform GUI widget framework (the classic Abstract Factory example!). As I remember the anecdote, the multiple-levels of indirection (polymorphic calls) in complex GUIs was a significant performance hit in the client code. Customers complained about GUIs being sluggish, and the "optimization" was to remove the indirections. In this case, performance trumped maintainability; the pattern was only making the coders happy, not the end users.

### DAO example

In terms of the DAO example you cite in the question, if you're coding an application that will never need to run with varying databases, then the DAO pattern is an unneeded level of complexity. In general, if your code doesn't need the benefit that a pattern is supposed to provide, applying that pattern will increase your application's complexity unnecessarily.

### Revolving door metaphor

Using buildings as a metaphor, let's consider a revolving door as a building design pattern. The following image comes from Wikipedia:

[image: Revolving door]

**You can "see" the additional complexity in such a door.** The benefits of revolving doors are in energy savings. They attempt to solve the problem where there are people frequently going in and out of a building, and opening/closing a standard door allows too much air to be exchanged between the inside the outside of the building each time.

It probably wouldn't make sense to install a revolving door as the entrance of a two-bedroom house, because there is not enough traffic to justify the additional complexity. The revolving door would still *work* in a two-bedroom house. The benefits in terms of energy savings would be small (and might actually be worse because of size and air-tightness relative to a conventional door). The door would surely cost more and would take up more space than a traditional door.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Love your metaphor. I always prefer KISS principle over Design Pattern, especially when Design Pattern are applied for the sake of applying instead of maintaining.

Answer (score 5):

Design patterns often lead to additional levels of abstraction around a problem, and if not handled correctly then too much abstraction can lead to complexity.

However, since design patterns provide a common vocabulary to communicate ideas they also reduce complexity and increase maintainability.

At the end of the day it's a double-edged sword, but I can't imagine a situation where I'd avoid using a design pattern...

Answer (score 5):

There's an infamous disease known as "Small Boy With A Pattern Syndrome" that usually strikes someone who has recently read the GoF book for the first time and suddenly sees patterns everywhere.  That can add complexity and unnecessary abstraction.

Patterns are best added to code as a discovery or refactoring to solve a particular problem, in my opinion.

Comment: [Head First Design Patterns](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1076324) discusses this in chapter 13 with the section "Your Mind on Patterns" where it starts with "The Beginner uses patterns everywhere," and progresses to "The Zen mind is able to see patterns where they fit naturally."

Answer (score 2):

In the short term, design patterns will often increase the complexity of the code.  They add extra abstractions in places they might not be strictly necessary.  However, in the long term they reduce complexity because future enhancements and changes fit into the patterns in a simple way.  Without the patterns, these changes would be much more intrusive and complexity would likely be much higher.

Take for example a decorator pattern.  The first time you use it, it will add complexity because now you have to define an interface for the object and create another class to add the decoration.  This could likely be done with a simple property and be done with.  However, when you get to 5 or 20 decoarations, the complexity with a decorator is much less than with properties.

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns increase the code and divide it into multiple parts. If the design pattern and concept is known then it doesn't sound complex but code based on design pattern you don't know then it looks complex.

Answer (score 1):

As Grover said, the power of Design patterns is dependent on the ability of programmers to recognize them when they see them. It's like reducing a mathematical problem to a simpler problem, and them solving the simpler one. To someone who doesn't realize this, though, it seems like you've just created another problem.

I think it's always a good idea to document explicitly, using comments and/or descriptive names, when you're using a pattern to solve a problem. This might even educate another programmer who comes across it about the pattern if he wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the "audience" i.e. the maintaining developers of the code base. If they are design pattern illiterate then yes it can increase complexity, because most things one doesn't understand are "complex".

If the team is design pattern literate, i.e. they understand the basics and understand the premise behind why design patterns are useful (and as important when they're not) then I think they reduce complexity.

After all Computer Science maybe a fledging science but it's got decades of experience under its belt. The chances are somebody has already solved your problem once before. Whether the answer is a design pattern, data structure or algorithm.

I rather like this humorous [explanation](http://dylanbeattie.blogspot.com/2009/02/specs-bugs-rocknroll.html) by [Dylan Beattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5017/). I recommend the read (if nothing else to waste five minutes on a Friday morning!)

Answer (score 1):

Design Patterns work like algorithms for Object Oriented Programming. Shows you how to put together objects in a meaningful relationship that performs a particular task. So I would say yes they reduce complexity by allowing you to understand the design of the software better. The same way with algorithms in procedural programs.

If I told you that X was using a Linked List with a Bubble Sort it would be a lot easier to following along with what the programmer was doing.

Answer (score 1):

They should ***neither*** increase nor decrease the complexity.

You should ***always*** use an appropriate design for your code. This may use common design patterns or not.

The main benefits to design patterns are

- By learning them you have added more design tools to your toolbox
- By learning their names, if you use them and put a comment stating the pattern you're using, it helps readers understand your design intent more concisely

When I teach patterns at Hopkins, the two big things I stress are:

- Patterns are all about *Communication of Intent*
- Don't use any of the specific patterns as a Golden Hammer; lock them in your toolbox and only pull them out if it makes sense for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I made some research about this topic in the scope of GoF patterns. I observed OO Metric value fluctuations after the design pattern refactorings, you can check it out using [this link](http://sites.google.com/site/barisaydinoz/barisaydinoz%27sthesis).

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns definitely adds complexity upfront in return for more modular, maintainable, flexible and extensible code in the long run. Perhaps the iterator pattern epitomizes it best.

Using index to iterate a list is clearly very simple and intuitive thing to do yet design patterns encapsulates it an iterator with is definitely more complex than a simple index.

The trade off is that it will be fair to say it has taken away the (implementation) simplicity but in return has made it more flexible removing iteration responsibility from the container and objectifying it which can be reusable.

That's design patterns for you.

Answer (score 0):

Design Patterns dont increase complexity, it can make things alot easier to read and maintain. It can be harder to new comers to integrate your developer team, but this effort will be benefitial as a whole.

Problem are Design Patterns as a whole, but the its abuse